# react-multi-carousel is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-multi-carousel

**I'm getting data from the state. Now I want to make a carousel slider using react-multi-carousel**

I am trying to implement https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel for a news card component that has data coming from the API. So far my code is as follows, but the carousel does not seem to be implementing?

**Child Component**

```
import Carousel from 'react-multi-carousel';
import 'react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css'
```

```
    const responsive = {
        superLargeDesktop: {
          breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
          items: 5
        },
        desktop: {
          breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
          items: 3
        },
        tablet: {
          breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
          items: 2
        },
        mobile: {
          breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
          items: 1
        }
    };
    const size = 15;
    const Itemlist = props.data.slice(0, size).map((item,id) => {
        return(
            <div className="item px-2 col-md-3" key={item.title}>
            <div className="alith_latest_trading_img_position_relative">
                <figure className="alith_post_thumb"> 
                <Link
                to={{
                    pathname : `/details/${id}`,
                }}
                >
                <img
                    alt=""
                    src={item.multimedia ? item.multimedia[0].url : image}
                    className="w-100 thumbnail"
                />
                </Link>
                </figure>
                <div className="alith_post_title_small">
                <Link
                to={{
                    pathname : `/details/${id}`,
                }}
                ><strong>{item.title.length > 30 ? item.title.substring(0,30) + ".." : item.title}</strong>
                </Link>
                <p className="meta">
                    <span>{`${moment(item.published_date).fromNow()}`}</span>
                </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    })
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Carousel responsive={responsive}>
                  {Itemlist}
            </Carousel>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

**Parent Component**

```
    state = {
        items : []
    }
    fetchLatestNews = () => {
        api.getRealFeed()
        .then(response=>{
            this.setState({
                items : response.data.results
            });
        })
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.fetchLatestNews();
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Item data={this.state.items}/>
        </React.Fragment>
)}};
```

Comment: Mind sharing all of the code for your news card component?

Comment: Added  @joshkmartinez. Please have a look

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have data in props.data ?

Comment: yes. I'm getting data  --  {item.title}

Comment: Is there anyone for help

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue,

Take a look at the specific props. You can add a class to the container, slide or item for adding your css rules. In my case,  I had to define a width to the containerClass.

```
<Carousel
   containerClass="carousel-container"
   itemClass="carousel-item"
>
 ... // Your carousel here
```

And in your css file:

```
.carousel-container {
  width: 100%;
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I had an issue where the carousel becomes empty when I set the prop infinity to true.
Turns out it was because the website I'm working on uses bootstrap rtl.

To fix the issue I just changed the direction of the carousel container to be ltr.
Something like this:

```
[dir="rtl"] .carousel-container{
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i fix it by adding width properties to the container class

if you using tailwind u need to can set the containerClass width

```
<Carousel
containerClass={`w-full`}
>
   {item}
</Carousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should add `import 'react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css'` to your top-level file NOT in the child component file. E.g: `_app.tsx` for NextJS. It took me about 30m to find out that.

Comment: I just plain forgot to import the styles. Everything worked once this was done.

PS: It would show (until the carousel shifted) when i went into developer tools and disabled the transform property, and then disappear when the carousel shifted. Writing this for google to index, in case anyone searches for these specific symptoms

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me in functional component: I'm late but it can be usefull to anyone in future.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";

    const SampleCode = props => {
    const [maindata, setMaindata] = useState([{'name':"one"}, 
    {'name':"two"}]);
    const responsive = {
    desktop: {
        breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
        items: 3,
        slidesToSlide: 3 // optional, default to 1.
    },
    tablet: {
        breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
        items: 2,
        slidesToSlide: 2 // optional, default to 1.
    },
    mobile: {
        breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
        items: 1,
        slidesToSlide: 1 // optional, default to 1.
    }
    };

    return (
    <div>

    <Carousel
    swipeable={false}
    draggable={false}
    showDots={true}
    responsive={responsive}
    ssr={false} // means to render carousel on server-side.
    infinite={true}
    autoPlay={false}
    autoPlaySpeed={1000}
    keyBoardControl={true}
    customTransition="all .5"
    transitionDuration={500}
    containerClass="carousel-container"
    // removeArrowOnDeviceType={["tablet", "mobile"]}
    //deviceType={true}//{this.props.deviceType}
    dotListClass="custom-dot-list-style"
    itemClass="carousel-item-padding-40-px"
    className='location-jobs '
   >

       {
        maindata.map((each) => {
            return (
                <div className='item p-3 mx-3 d-flex'>
                    {each.name}
                </div>

            )
        })
        }

         </Carousel>
       </div>
    );

}
```

export default SampleCode;

Answer (score 0):

It is having width issues like I was too using in my project, I have to set the width by using media queries. I don't know why the developer hasn't fixed the issue, but you can try giving a default width in inspect section and then setting up the width by using media queries.